# Discrepancy between calculated and simulated cutoff frequencies of a bandpass filter

Tags: filter, pspice, band-pass, band

I'm trying to simulate a bandpass filter with the following components:

- C1 = 2 µF
- R1 = 100 Ω
- R2 = 10 kΩ
- C2 = 8 nF

I calculated the cutoff frequencies using the following formulas:

- Low cutoff frequency: fL = 1 / (2 * pi * R1 * C1) = 795.77 Hz
- High cutoff frequency: fH = 1 / (2 * pi * R2 * C2) = 1989.95 Hz

However, when I simulated the circuit in PSpice, I got different results: the lower cutoff frequency was 483 Hz and the higher cutoff frequency was 3.28 kHz. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

[image: PSpice Schematic]

[image: |Vo| vs freq Graph:]

[image: Graph of AvdB vs Frequency]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of your circuit?

Comment: Please show your schematic/simulation. Note that input and output impedances affect the solution, so understanding the test setup is critical in getting a sensible result.

Comment: @mapplejacks check the post now, ive added the schematic and the graphs

Comment: @Kartman ive added the schematic above

Comment: Try a buffer (amplifier by 1 with high input impedance, low output impedance) between filters.

Comment: is the formula i used correct to calculate the lower and upper cutoff frequencies?

Comment: You apply the formulas valid for pure lowpass and pure highpass 1st order filters, but in the passband filter the highpass and the lowpass are connected, and the resulting transfer function cannot be described with the figures valid for disconnected branches. THe circuit is linear, but we use nonlinear operation (magnitude of the complex voltage, mag(Vout)), when we calculate cutoff frequencies

Comment: I'm assuming since these are idealistic purely high-pass and low-pass filters, there will be some roll-off or residual frequencies that pass to the cascading filter and causing the discrepancy?

could you show a step by step solution to find the simulated results?

Comment: There is the dB function in Probe: just type dB(V(out)) and you will have the node magnitude in dB provided the ac stimulus is 1 V and not 7 V as in your example. Same for the phase, Vp is a possible function if I remember well.

Comment: @HabibKhan All the drawn circuits are 'idealistic', when captured into schematics, but do you believe that 'residual frequencies', not to mention 'low-entropy' etc. are adequate words to explain BPF cutoff frequency misunderstanding? I can understand a freshman struggling with this 'problem', even an experienced engineer can fall victim of mental fatigue to the end of the 7-day workweek, but what is a real "common error", it is to write a 500-word text with multiple formulas and images as an answer. Well, my hunch was right, yours is a trick question, a question with consequences.

Answer (score 6):

The circuit you show is a second-order bandpass filter. You cannot apply the classical design expressions pertaining to single-stage \$CR\$ or \$RC\$ filters, it is a common error. The reason is that the first \$CR\$ network is loaded by the input impedance of the cascaded low-pass filter which obviously affects the response of the high-pass filter. The low-pass filter is itself driven by the output impedance of the high-pass filter and it also changes its response. Therefore, either you isolate the blocks with a unity buffer in between, or you determine the entire transfer function.

To determine this transfer function, you have the choice to apply the brute-force method which consists, as an option among many, to determine the Thévenin impedance driving \$R_2\$ and then proceed with an impedance divider. You then must expand, factor and rearrange the expression for design purposes: a transfer function is not enough, you determine it for *design-oriented analysis* or D-OA, a term forged by Dr. Middlebrook. It means that the expression must be written in a way, so-called *low-entropy*, that it is useful for designing your filter, for instance, how to set the frequency and amplitude of this filter in the mid-band area, where are the zeroes and poles and so on.

To get there quickly, I use the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs that are described below. By resorting to simple individual sketches, you can quickly determine the time constants and gains of the circuits, very often without involving algebra. The process is shown below:

[image]

You first check the presence of a dc gain but there is none as \$C_1\$ blocks the signal when \$s=0\$. Then you reduce the excitation to 0 V and "look" through all capacitors connecting terminals to determine the resistance \$R\$ you "see". Combined with the capacitor, \$RC\$ will give you the time constants you need. Then, for the numerator, you alternatively set each energy-storing element in its high-frequency state (a short circuit for a capacitor) and determine the various gains in these modes. You then assemble the transfer function and factor it under a compact second-order polynomial where a resonant frequency and a quality factor show up. It is time to test the ac response and the integrity of the expression in a Mathcad sheet:

[image]

The response between the low-entropy form and the brute-force expression are rigorously identical. You see how powerful and quick are the FACTs that I described in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1960405195) on the subject. What is cool too is that if you spot an error in the end, like a deviation in magnitude or phase when comparing ac responses, you can identify the guilty sketch and fix it immediately without restarting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

When you cascade simple filters like this, you have several potential issues.

1. Loading can cause interactions. The first RC has a load less than infinite. The second RC has a non-zero source impedance. But, your second stage has impedances two orders of magnitude greater, so this is not your primary issue.
2. The cutoffs can interact; your cutoffs are very close together. If you don't want them to interact, you need a larger frequency difference. 10X difference would be better, but you will still have interaction unless you go to about 100X difference.

Here I plotted the output if a buffer is placed between the stages, the result is almost the same as the simulation of the actual circuit.

[image]

Edit: Added full circuit calculations. The maximum deviation between buffered and unbuffered is only 0.025 dB.

[image]

This was all done with Excel, a clumsy tool for this purpose, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF7LHf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}
\end{alignat*}
\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}
\end{alignat*}
\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{R}_4}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I3 == V2/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R2 + R3 + R4) Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> ((R3 + R4) Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> (R2 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> (R2 R4 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))}}
```

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\displaystyle\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\displaystyle\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_1=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2}\tag6$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\right)+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\text{s}}{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{s}^2+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\text{s}+1}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\underbrace{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}_{:=\space\epsilon_1}\cdot\text{s}}{\displaystyle\underbrace{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}_{:=\space\epsilon_2}\cdot\text{s}^2+\left(\underbrace{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}_{:=\space\epsilon_3}\right)\cdot\text{s}+1}\\
\\
&=\frac{\epsilon_1\text{s}}{\epsilon_2\text{s}^2+\epsilon_3\text{s}+1}
\end{alignat*}
\tag7
$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\displaystyle\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\displaystyle\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\displaystyle\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\displaystyle\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). So we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\epsilon_1\text{j}\omega}{\displaystyle\epsilon_2\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2+\epsilon_3\text{j}\omega+1}=\frac{\epsilon_1\omega\text{j}}{1-\epsilon_2\omega^2+\epsilon_3\omega\text{j}}\tag8$$

So, the absolute value of the transfer function is given by:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\epsilon_1\omega}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\epsilon_3\omega\right)^2}}\tag9$$

Now, we can solve for the maximum:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\partial\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|}{\displaystyle\partial\omega}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega_0:=\omega=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\epsilon_2}}\tag{10}$$

Now, we can solve for the cut-off frequencies:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\epsilon_1}{\displaystyle\epsilon_3}\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega_\pm:=\omega=\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\epsilon_3^2+4\epsilon_2}\pm\epsilon_3}{\displaystyle2\epsilon_2}\tag{11}$$

We can conclude that \$\displaystyle\omega_+>\omega_-\$.

For, your circuit you'll find: \$\displaystyle\text{f}_-\approx483.2\space\text{Hz}\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{f}_+\approx3276.37\space\text{Hz}\$.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
R1 = 1/(s*C1);
R2 = (1/10)*1000;
R3 = 10*1000;
R4 = 1/(s*C2);
C1 = 2*10^(-6);
C2 = 8*10^(-9);
s = I*w;
w = 2*Pi*f;
h = FullSimplify[(V2 /. 
      Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
         I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I3 == V2/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, 
         V2}][[1]])/Vi];
H = FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[ComplexExpand[Re[h]]^2 + ComplexExpand[Im[h]]^2], 
   Assumptions -> f >= 0];
fmax = FullSimplify[f /. Solve[{D[H, f] == 0, f >= 0}, f][[1]]];
N[FullSimplify[
  Solve[{H == (1/Sqrt[2])*((H) /. f -> (fmax)), f >= 0}, f]]]//Flatten
```

Comment: Nice derivation, but you didn't answer the question.

Comment: You can automate this using gEDA or Lepton EDA. See https://github.com/noqsi/gEDAmath

Answer (score 0):

The question in its original form, without graphics attached, is of the kind that is known in programmers' ecosystem as "codegolf": you are given the function (BPF) and component values, the problem is to recover the circuit topology. There are two capacitors and two resistors, so this is a first order filter with only a few possible implementation topologies. I tried this one

[image: bandpass-variant]

then another one

```
* bandpass-694507.asc
C1 N001 in 2µ
R1 N001 0 0.1K
R2 out N001 10K
C2 out 0 8n
V1 in 0 AC 1
.ac oct 12 400 4000
.meas AC f_low FIND frequency WHEN mag(V(out))=voutmax/sqrt(2) CROSS=1
.meas AC f_high FIND frequency WHEN mag(V(out))=voutmax/sqrt(2) CROSS=2
.meas voutmax max(mag(V(out)))
.end
```

and the second try was successful, but at that very moment the OP had satisfied the requests for schematic drawing and the codegolf problem was gone.

Still, I was (slightly) curious how SE experts would explain that the transfer function of BPF in this configuration cannot be reduced to a product of LPF and HPF transfer functions.

I would recommend the struggling student to concentrate on schematic topology instead of calculations. You can suggest the student to solve a voltage divider in a ladder configuration

[image: voltage-divider]

and if the student is writing

```
Vout = Vin * R2/(R1+R2) * R4/(R3+R4)
```

the student should be advised to return to the fundamentals of the lumped circuits.

In my practice, this example never fails to assure the student that however difficult are calculations with complex impedances, there are no royal road to geometry ((C) Euclid). And to Electrical Engineering, too. Ergo, calculations have to be done.

Also, when teaching circuit basics to computer-science students, the difficult calculation problem is somewhat mitigated by their coding skills and you can request the solution, for example, in the form

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C1 = 2E-6
g1 = 1/100
g2 = 1/10E3
C2 = 8E-9

freqlim_low = 400
freqlim_high = 4000

freq = np.linspace(freqlim_low, freqlim_high, freqlim_high-freqlim_low, endpoint=False)
omega = 2 * np.pi * freq

Vout = 1 / (1 + 1 / (1j * omega * C1 * \
                 (g2 + 1j * omega * C2) / (g1 * g2 + 1j * omega * (g1 + g2) * C2) \
                 )) \
                 * \
                 1 / (1 + 1j * omega * C2 / g2)

plt.figure('BPF transfer function')
plt.title('V(483Hz)/Vout_max = %1.3g and V(3278Hz)/Vout_max = %1.3g' %(np.abs(Vout[483 - 400])/np.abs(Vout[1270 - 400]), np.abs(Vout[3278 - 400])/np.abs(Vout[1270 - 400])))
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(Vout))
#plt.plot(freq, np.angle(Vout))
plt.show()
```

The students might even find this form of homework submission appealing to their preferences.

Of course, referring to Euclid, you insist that derivation of the formula with complex impedances must be done "by hand", at least once in lifetime.

Comment: thanks for your answer however i m not familiar with Netlists. Is the formulas i used correct for this type of filter? If yes, how is the answer so vastly different from the simulated values?

Comment: @greybeard never posted to puzzle and cannot apply >! spoilers. Would you please edit my answer and put network lists in 'spoilers'?

Comment: @Habib Khan So you say you published this 'brain teaser' inadvertently.  Still, it is good. Let me answer your comment after other posters have a try, ok? Your question is very good and useful, and there is an opportunity for you to learn netlists.  Your formulas are correct, it is a problem of interpretation.

Comment: @greybeard thank you. Unfortunately, the feature not only hides, but also destroys formatting, but with these short netlists the formatting is not a problem. But still, do you know if the spoiler can be applied, and the formatting can be kept?